# How can I crop an OpenStreetMap and export it using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I want to crop an OpenStreetMap (a specific area, for example a town). I want to save and export this cropped area using QGIS (format could be .osm or .shp).

I have searched everywhere but I could not find a valid answer. Is this not possible? One can crop an OpenStreetMap directly but it is limited by the size of cropping area. I assume this is a fairly common practice. What are the alternatives available?

I am using QGIS 3.10 over Ubuntu 18.

Comment: What features are you interested in? How do you access OSM? What have you tried?

Comment: Initially i was tried to get the elevation data of an area referenced by osm .I want to export it to a software which accepts .osm and .shp files. I managed to get the elevation data and exported it but i am not able to crop the osm for that area and export it. 
I have openstreetmap available from xyzTiles of qgis. 
I am interested in the crop version of the map so that i can export it with desired format, not as image. Please suggest , i am not from GIS field but i need the elevation data and the map of that area.

Comment: You can try Overpass, e.g. I did something here [Exporting buildings and their types with Overpass](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310313/exporting-buildings-and-their-types-with-overpass).

Comment: I tried overpass. It gives certain elevation data(not all). Another issue is that,overpass only gives the elevation data, not necessarily the map itself which can be exported. 

I tried the vector>geoprocessing tools>clip . But for the input layer, OSM is not available, so i am not able to clip as well

Comment: OSM doesn't contain elevation data (except for peaks and a few other objects). So you will need a different source for this data.